# installation of pr2 simulator

Tags: ros, simulation, installation, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm new to ROS. I'm following the tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/StartingPR2Simulation

when I do:

rosmake pr2_gazebo

I get the following error:

rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pr2_gazebo']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/randaz/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111110-144213
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pr2_gazebo'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['pr2_gazebo']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

I also cannot do:

roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch
[pr2_gazebo] is not a package or launch file name

I don't know if something is missing in my installation.
I installed:

sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full

and

sudo apt-get install ros-electric-wg-pr2-apps

Do I need something else?
I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11882/installation-of-pr2-simulator/) by [randaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1321/randaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/2847/ubuntu-install-of-electric-pr2-desktop

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you're running Ubuntu, you can ignore any rosmake instructions and install the debs instead. All you should need to do is

```
apt-get install ros-electric-pr2-simulator
```

then start with step 2 from the tutorial that you linked.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1